# Fix an element horizontally, but not vertically with css

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay element in a container which scrolls horizontally.

I want this overlay to be fixed in place horizontally, but if I scroll the window, the overlay should scroll along with the page.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lvy9uq0n/1/

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 3000px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="overlay">
      Overlay

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div syle="height:1000px">

  Test
</div>
```

TLDR: Element should be fixed inside a container horizontally but not vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take the overlay div out of the normal flow of the document, which is why I suppose you used the `position: fixed` class. However, that takes the element out of the document flow *and* it fixes the vertical position relative to the browser window.

Try `position: absolute` to position your overlay outside the flow, but still have it scroll normally with the document. You can center it using `left: 0; right: 0` and `margin: auto`. I'm not sure how far you'd like the overlay from the `top`:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```